Flutter application iOS google login is not validating in Backend
I'm implementing flutter application for iOS and android apps. I have set up google login feature with firebaseconsole. So far so good, it's doing the login perfectly in the app side. But I want to verify that token in the server side. I'm using spring boot where apps are sending me the token after google login as an API call. This is where I'm having issues with. The spring boot app is able to validate the token from the browser perfectly fine but not from the app. What could be the issue?
The main difference I'm seeing so far is the configuration. Firebase console configuration is using differnt google client id and secret for the browser login and apps login. But they are being managed in the same console. Could that be the issue?
Here is how I'm using the google login in the flutter:
_googleSignIn.signIn().then((result){
result?.authentication.then((googleKey){
print(googleKey.accessToken);
print(googleKey.idToken);
**// This is where I am calling the login verification process sending googleKey.idToken**
print(_googleSignIn.currentUser?.displayName);
}).catchError((err){
print('inner error');
});
}).catchError((err){
print('error occured');
});


Have  you added googleservicesinfo.plist file in your application ?

yes, it is there.

Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34147663/833395

Please cehck if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/33018286/833395

Adding this solution here for anyone for future reference.
The token can be verified with making the get request to the url: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token={token_value}
replace {token_value} with the actual value.
you'll get 200 (OK) status with the json object with name, email etc. if the token is valid.
